# Get element at specified position - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using Javascript how can I identify the element at a given position? Basically I'm looking to write a function that takes two input parameters (the x and y coordinates) and returns the html element at the position on the screen represented by the parameters.

Comment: [elementsFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint)

Answer (score 271, accepted):

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)
```

https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-document-elementfrompoint

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint

Comment: I'm amazed this worked in ie 5.5 and is not used that much today.

Comment: I have tried this method and it measure the position according to the document. How do I use it relative to the parent element ?

Comment: If at the coordinate x, y, there is a frame or iframe you will get the frame, rather than the element at that location.

Comment: A jsfiddle example would be really awesome! Seems amazing! Can't wait to try it!

Comment: Quite amazing this exists, I develop for like 10 years and never heard of this function, thanks.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the native JavaScript `elementFromPoint(x, y)` method, that returns the element at coordinates x,y in the viewport.

See the [elementFromPoint w3c draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-document-elementfrompoint)

And, a code sample:

```js
function changeColor(newColor) {
    // Get the element placed at coords (2, 2)
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(2, 2);
    // Set the foreground color to the element
    elem.style.color = newColor;
}
```

```html
<p id="para1">Change this text color using the following buttons.</p>
<button onclick="changeColor('blue');">Blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('red');">Red</button>
```

You can use `setInterval()` to continuously check the element's hover event but it's not recommended, try to use `.hover(...)` and css instead to enhance the application performance.

Answer (score 6):

To get the topmost element at a specific position relative to the viewport, [`document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) can be used.

To obtain an array of all the elements at a specific position, use [`document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint).

In both cases, `x` is the horizontal coordinate which is relative to the left of the viewport and `y` is the vertical coordinate which is relative to the top of the viewport.

Comment: Hi @Unmitigated this method seems to not be available anymore (tried Chrome in linux and in mac), do you know with what it might have been replaced ?

Comment: @GeorgePligoropoulos It still works for me. Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: believe it or not it was a typo. so please disregard my comment. many thanks