# Using javascript, get div id given x and y location

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery find element at a particular position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/jquery-find-element-at-a-particular-position)

In the browser, if I am given either 1. css locations ( top, left ) or 2. absolute locations (offset.x, offset.y, for example), is there a way to get what div is in that location beside a brute force search through all the divs on the screen? Or even a brute force through the subset of divs I care about?

Comment: Like this? [jquery find element at a particular position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/jquery-find-element-at-a-particular-position)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259585/get-element-at-specified-position-javascript

Comment: `elementFromPoint` uses screen coordinates and acts differently when zooming/scrolling. It's not exactly what the OP wants, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
var $element = $(element);
```

If you e.g, want the ID you then do the following:

```
$element.attr('id');
```