# Get element at specified position - JavaScript and mapped it back to source HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to write HTML annotation service. So I want to attach an annotation to HTML elements where a user clicked. So far [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259585/get-element-at-specified-position-javascript) helped me find HTML element. However I want to locate the element back in DOM tree.

So if I traverse DOM tree down until I met the element, will be my traverse path uniquely identify the element, so I can restore annotation each time, or browsers can build DOM tree differently and there is a risk of changing browser can bring me in trouble?

Another option can be look for position of found element innerHTML in BODY.innerHTML. However if I have repeatable elements I can't provide exact mapping. Any other suggestions? Please do not advise to add some unique id for every HTML element and then use it. It will bloat HTML and I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use `jquery`.

Can then cycle through each matching element and use `this` to address the one you want when you find it.

Example:

```
$('.class-name-of-element').each(function() {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid red'); // or whatever you want to do with it
})
```