# Call "Inspect element" on pixel position (x,y)

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Given a pixel position on a webpage, say x = 40 and y = 100, is there a way to invoke the "Inspect Element" option from Chrome dev tools on this pixel programmatically? Can puppeteer do it or some other way?

Comment: This is _not_ opening Chrome dev tools, but getting the element at x, y using plain JavaScript: `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259585/get-element-at-specified-position-javascript

Comment: @Wumms I think you identified correctly the issue in my question. If I could get the element at (x, y) with elementFromPoint() then I could do whatever analysis on it that I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I found the answer to my question. I should've instead asked if there was a programmatic way to get HTML element at pixel position (x, y), to which @Wumm's comment above answers it. You can use elementFromPoint(x, y) to get HTML element.

Secondly, the answer to the way I posed my question is answered by @zfrisch. So there is no automatic way to invoke Devtools themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer there is no way to do this currently.

per the [Chromium issues page](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277)

> "We only allow explicit devtools opening."

This means that you must manually open the inspector through either keyboard shortcut or menu selection.

**Note** The way around this is to use a macro service of some kind that can emit keyboard events(such as `ctrl+shift+j`) and mouse clicks(`to right click and click inspect element`). however, it is still a manual process in reality. Everything that can be done on a computer can be turned into a macro on some level, so it's a bit out of scope to explain how to do this.

Comment: Thanks @zfrisch. Sounds like I'll have to setup up some higher level macro to setup the mouse cursor at some point (x, y).